# View is added to UIViewControllerWrapperView, but it doesn't appear correctly

Tags: c#, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to show a loading indicator on top of a `UITableViewController`. Therefore I add my subview to `myTableViewontroller.View.Superview` which is the `UIViewControllerWrapperView`. This works so far, but not in all cases. If the `UITableViewController` is added the first time on the navigation stack, I can display the loading indicator as often as I'd like. If I pop the `UITableViewController` and push a new instance of it on the navigation stack again, the loading indicator doesn't appear. Successive calls make the loading indicator appear again!

I tried to setup my constraints in `UpdateConstraints`, `LayoutSubviews`, but it didn't helped. Somehow the frame seems to be zero in height. Inspecting frames shows the following:

*Normal case:*

```
parent:{X=0,Y=0,Width=320,Height=480}
hud:{X=0,Y=0,Width=0,Height=0}
parent - before setting up constraints{X=0,Y=0,Width=320,Height=480}
hud - after hud showing: {X=0,Y=0,Width=279,5,Height=0}
parent:{X=0,Y=0,Width=320,Height=480}
hud:{X=0,Y=0,Width=320,Height=480}
```

*Failing case*

```
parent:{X=0,Y=0,Width=320,Height=480}
hud:{X=0,Y=0,Width=0,Height=0}
parent - before setting up constraints{X=0,Y=0,Width=320,Height=480}
hud - after hud showing: {X=-20,Y=59,Width=279,5,Height=0}
```

So `LayoutSubviews` seems to called twice in normal case, because *parent:*  and *hud:* line are outputted there. The *-20* comes from one constraint used by me, which I get rid off in one of the next steps through using differnt constraints (limiting widht/height).

If I add a minimum height I can see the hud under the navigation bar on top left of the table view, but it is cutted off through the navigation bar and is not centered. The same behavior occurs if I try to limit the width/height between zero and my defined maximum size:

```
NSLayoutConstraint widthConstraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this.hudContainer, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.LessThanOrEqual, this, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 1, -40);
widthConstraint1.Priority = 750;
NSLayoutConstraint widthConstraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this.hudContainer, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1, 0);
widthConstraint2.Priority = 1000;
NSLayoutConstraint heightConstraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this.hudContainer, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.LessThanOrEqual, this, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, 1, -100);
heightConstraint1.Priority = 750;
NSLayoutConstraint heightConstraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this.hudContainer, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1, 0);
heightConstraint2.Priority = 1000;
AddConstraints(new NSLayoutConstraint[] { widthConstraint1, widthConstraint2, heightConstraint1, heightConstraint2});
```

Here the maximum width is not respected.

This code is used by me for adding the hud as subview and setting up the main constraints:

```
this.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
this.parentView.AddSubview(this);

NSMutableDictionary viewsDictionary = new NSMutableDictionary();
viewsDictionary["hud"] = this;

this.parentView.LayoutIfNeeded();
Console.WriteLine("parent - before setting up constraints" + this.parentView.Frame);

this.parentView.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.parentView, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 1, 0));
this.parentView.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.parentView, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, 1, 0));
this.parentView.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.parentView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, 0));
this.parentView.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.parentView, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, 1, 0));
this.parentView.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.parentView, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, 0));
this.parentView.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.parentView, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 1, 0));
this.parentView.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.parentView, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, 1, 0));
this.parentView.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.parentView, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, 1, 0));
```

This is the code for removing and hidding the hud:

```
this.Alpha = 0.0f;
RemoveFromSuperview();
```

I'm running out of ideas. How can I solve this problem? Perhaps someone can give me a hint how can I debug this better. The code presented here is in C#, but you can provide code samples in Objective-C/Swift!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not manually add views to a `UIViewControllerWrapperView` since it's an internal API. Doing so can lead to unpredictable results.

Instead, add your loading indicator as a subview to the `view` property of your `UITableViewController`. Maybe this already solves your issue.

One more thing: if your HUD is a `UIActivityIndicatorView`, you don't need to remove it in order to hide it. Just set the `hidesWhenStopped` property to `true`; then the indicator will automatically get hidden when `stopAnimating`is called, and will reappear when `startAnimating`is called.

**Edit:**

As you pointed out, adding the HUD to the view directly can lead to positioning issues. One way around this is to manually set a container view (a plain `UIView`) which hosts the table view and the HUD:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let tableView = self.tableView
  let containerView = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
  containerView.addSubview(tableView)
  containerView.addSubview(spinner)      
  view = containerView

  spinner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: spinner, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
  view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: spinner, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

  spinner.startAnimating()
}
```

Note that this example uses a simple activity indicator which has an intrinsic size, so to center it only two constraints are needed; for your HUD, you may have to add more complex constraints.

Comment: Adding to the ´View` property has the disadvantage that the HUD is not centered anymore. I would have to implement a feature in each `UITableView`, which would update the position. Hence I thought I could use `UIViewControllerWrapperView`. Do you have a solution for that? Thanks for the tip with the `UIActivityIndicatorView`. Didn't know that. Because I also have a label on it I have to hide the complete wrapper including the indicator.

Comment: I edited my post to add a solution for this problem. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for updating you answer. I have the following disadvantages with your solution: each `UITableViewController` has to be adapted, and in my development environment I have more efforts for assuring memory management. Seems that there is no other solution to this problem (perhaps adding to the `view` of `UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow()`, but here the complete view controller is hidden). Perhaps you have another good idea, that would be awesome!

Comment: You could create a base class which handles the displaying/hiding of your HUD. Might be a good idea anway if you have lots of such controllers. Alternatively, have you looked for existing HUD libraries, e.g. at Cocoapods? There are quite a few of these and they might just do what you want...

Comment: What do you mean with the base class exactly? I have a separate class for my HUD. There is a method in it which handles the displaying and hiding, but with the above mentioned difficulties. Before I wrote myself one I looked into existing libraries, but you create an additionioal dependency over which I have no control. If the library isn't supported anymore (new iOS version) you're out of luck if you can't fix it yourself. My class on the other side is relatively simple. I think the difficulities with centering on `UITableViewController` or `UICollectionViewController` would still exist then.

Comment: Another option would be to add the HUD to `navigationController.view`, but it takes the space including the navigation bar ... Now I had a look into some available libraries and most of them ask for a view. So they all have this sort of difficulties.

Comment: Base class: create a subclass of `UITableViewController` which handles the HUD creation/display in `viewDidLoad` (let's call it `HUDTableViewController`), and then use this class as super class for your various table view controllers. This way you have the HUD functionality in all your controllers, no extra code needed.

Answer (score 0):

I took the approach suggested by [dr_barto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5471218/dr-barto). I defined my new base class `HUDTableViewController`, which is my new `UITableViewController`. So I'm subclassing from `HUDTableViewController` instead of `UITableViewController`.

My HUD gets the following view:

`TableView.Superview` (inside of my subclassed `HUDTableViewController`)

One would have to add additional methods and also implement such base class for `UICollectionViewController`. Here I'm presenting an example for `UITableViewController`:

```
public class HUDTableViewController : UIViewController, IUITableViewDataSource, IUITableViewDelegate, IDisposable
{
    private UITableView tableView;

    public UITableView TableView
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tableView;
        }
        set
        {
            this.tableView = value;
        }
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        this.tableView = new UITableView();
        this.tableView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

        this.tableView.WeakDelegate = this;
        this.tableView.WeakDataSource = this;

        UIView parentView = new UIView();
        parentView.AddSubview(this.tableView);
        View = parentView;

        NSMutableDictionary viewsDictionary = new NSMutableDictionary();
        viewsDictionary["parent"] = parentView;
        viewsDictionary["tableView"] = this.tableView;

        parentView.AddConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("H:|[tableView]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
        parentView.AddConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("V:|[tableView]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
    }

    [Foundation.Export("numberOfSectionsInTableView:")]
    public virtual System.nint NumberOfSections(UIKit.UITableView tableView)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual System.nint RowsInSection(UIKit.UITableView tableview, System.nint section)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual UIKit.UITableViewCell GetCell(UIKit.UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [Foundation.Export("tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:")]
    public virtual void RowSelected(UIKit.UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [Foundation.Export("tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:")]
    public virtual System.nfloat GetHeightForHeader(UIKit.UITableView tableView, System.nint section)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [Foundation.Export("tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:")]
    public virtual UIKit.UIView GetViewForHeader(UIKit.UITableView tableView, System.nint section)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [Foundation.Export("tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:")]
    public virtual void WillDisplay(UIKit.UITableView tableView, UIKit.UITableViewCell cell, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

As one can see I add an additional view behind the `UITableView`. Now I can use the superview of the table view for my HUD. Seems to work so far.

Lazy alternatives (with different behavior):

- Use `Window` property:

  `UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow().View`
- Use `NavigationController`:

  `NavigationController.View`